# multiple input="type" on a page with specific type of upload for each

Tags: html

I'm having multiple file upload input type on a registration page with each specifying a particular type of file which can be uploaded, `first is images`, `second document` and the `third is videos`.

What I've realized is when a user clicks on any of the file upload and the file chooser opens, it only allows for images to select irrespective of the user clicked

```
<div class="image-upload" style="padding-right: 20px;">
  <label for="file-input">
    <img src="../../assets/img/image.png" width="30px" />
  </label>
  <input accept="image/jpeg, image/png" id="file-input" type="file" (change)="fileChangeEvent($event)" />
</div>

<div class="image-upload" style="padding-right: 20px;">
  <label for="file-input">
    <img src="../../assets/img/document.png" width="30px" />
  </label>
  <input accept=".doc, .docx, .pdf" id="file-input" type="file" (change)="fileChangeEvent($event)" />
</div>

<div class="image-upload" style="padding-right: 20px;">
  <label for="file-input">
    <img src="../../assets/img/video.png" width="30px" />
  </label>
  <input accept="video/*" id="file-input" type="file" (change)="fileChangeEvent($event)" />
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Its working fine at my end, What I can see is, You have allotted same ID to each input tag. Please give different IDs( Its unique for each tag).
Please try with below code:

```html
<div class="image-upload" style="padding-right: 20px;">
  <label for="file-input-img">
    <img src="../../assets/img/image.png" width="30px" />
  </label>
  <input accept="image/jpeg, image/png" id="file-input-img" type="file" (change)="fileChangeEvent($event)" />
</div>

<div class="image-upload" style="padding-right: 20px;">
  <label for="file-input-doc">
    <img src="../../assets/img/document.png" width="30px" />
  </label>
  <input accept=".doc, .docx, .pdf" id="file-input-doc" type="file" (change)="fileChangeEvent($event)" />
</div>

<div class="image-upload" style="padding-right: 20px;">
  <label for="file-input-video">
    <img src="../../assets/img/video.png" width="30px" />
  </label>
  <input accept="video/*" id="file-input-video" type="file" (change)="fileChangeEvent($event)" />
</div>
```